# Can't get errors to be displayed in an Rails "remote: true" form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm trying to display errors messages in my ajax form (the code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306380/error-handling-with-ajax-in-rails-3) question):

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if params[:commit] == "Publish"
      @post.status = "Published"
    elsif params[:commit] == "Save Draft"
      @post.status = "Draft"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if @post.save && @post.status == "Published"
          flash[:success] = "Post published"
          redirect_to @post
        elsif @post.save && @post.status == "Draft"
          flash[:success] = "Post saved as draft"
          render 'edit'
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end
      format.js do
        @post.save
      end
    end
  end
```

**posts/create.js.erb:**

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  alert('There are errors.');
  <%= render :partial=>'js_errors', :locals=> { :target=> @post } %>
<% else %>
  $('.busy').html('Saved.');
<% end %>
```

**js_errors.js.erb:**

```
<% target.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
  $('.busy').append('<p><%= escape_javascript( error ) %></p>');
<% end %>
```

**posts/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Publish", class: "publish btn btn-primary pull-left" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save Draft", class: "save-draft btn btn-default pull-left" %>
    <div class="busy pull-left">
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But for some reason nothing displays (`.busy` always remain empty).

In the console I can see that `js_errors.js.erb` is being displayed:

> Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-04 18:02:18 +0800
>   Processing by PostsController#create as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"Qfn6HsPPDxyB1t4bM/OQKPbJ/aoAMkp74y0Z6xkoXCY=",
>   "post"=>{"title"=>"", "content"=>"", "tag_list"=>""},
>   "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save Draft"}   User Load (0.7ms) 
>   SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" =
>   'ljl0ZsuoiHg0Jilz8bgy-g' LIMIT 1    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
>   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction   Rendered posts/_js_errors.js.erb
>   (3.8ms)   Rendered posts/create.js.erb (7.5ms) Completed 200 OK in
>   25ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)

What could be the problem?

(I do see the validation messages if I remove `remote:true` from the form).

**EDIT:**

I noticed `alert('There are errors.');` is not being triggered. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a naming problem. You're asking to render the *partial* `js_errors`, which would be called `_js_errors.js.erb`; but you say your file is actually called `js_errors.js.erb` (no leading underscore).

Try adding the underscore and see if that helps matters.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the file is titled `_js_errors.js.erb` and that it is being rendered correctly.

Comment: @Chowlett I discovered the error. I had this on top of the file: `<%#<% elsif @post.status == "Published" && @post.id? %>%>` somehow triggering a "silent error." Sorry. What should we do delete the question or answer my own question?

Comment: I'd delete it if I were you, glad you fixed it :)

Comment: @alexchenco - probably delete it. It's not going to be of use for posterity!

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar problem a few days ago. I used `remote => true` option in my form to use Ajax in my Rails 3 application. After that, I have been looking for solution for validating my form fields. After trying a good number of jQuery / Javascript approaches (none of them worked for me though) I came to know about a superb gem called client_side_validations. It is very easy to install by following the instructions on github link (https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations). It works like charm for client side validation of form fields, an awesome gem indeed. Hope this helps with people who are tired of looking for a simple solution for client side validation of model fields after using Ajax in Rails 3 application.