# How to show validations error on submit form via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My form is little complex, everything is on landing page `welcome/index.html.erb`.

This form has two tabs: **products** and **users**.

Under products tab there are features like:

- create new product
- show list of products

For each product there are options like:

- add user to product

When I click on **create new product** there is div open which has form for new product.

I tried using `client_side_validation` but no success (from google search it looks like this gem is not supported for rails 3.2.13).

How can I show validation error when I submit my form using jquery?

```
this.submit(function() {
  //$('#createPolicy').slideToggle();
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
})
return this;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you really doing an ajax call in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery?rq=1 there is something like $.ajax({....})? if so you need register some kind of callback method which informs you about the result of your action and you need to react on it appropriately, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306380/error-handling-with-ajax-in-rails-3 can help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ajax POST at all. If `submit` function returns falase, page won't be reloaded.

```
$('#button').submit(function() {
  if($('input#field_1').val().length===0){
  $('.errors').text("Can't be blank") } 
  return false
  else if(#more conditionals) {

  } #...
  else{
return true}
})
```

This way validation works both user-side and server-side. If you want to do it through AJAX request, you should provide response of method on case true,which also needs to rework content of page, on case false, providing errors meassages.  A lot of work to do. I believe request is needed only when your validation is based on DB data, such as uniqueness.